# Capturing counter around switch inside anonymous classes inside some cases?

Tags: java, variables, switch-statement, anonymous-class, shadowing

I was trying to write a switch inside a loop, where inside 2/5 of the cases, an anonymous class is made, which captures the loop counter. It's not straight forward because the counter needs to be final to be able to be captured by the anonymous inner class. The solution is simple though, just make a `final int i_` which gets set to the counter variable. The problem is that it doesn't work (I guess because there's more than one case). Here is an extremely simplified piece of code that has the same problem as in my real code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.*;
enum E {A,B,C,D,E}
class A {
    static void s() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    static Semaphore s = new Semaphore(2); // 2 cores
    public static void main(String[] _){
        LinkedList<E> es = new LinkedList<E>();
        es.push(E.A);
        es.push(E.D);
        es.push(E.B);
        es.push(E.C);
        es.push(E.E);
        es.push(E.C);
        es.push(E.C);
        es.push(E.E);
        es.push(E.A);
        es.push(E.A);
        f(es);
    }
    static void f(List<E> es) {
        int i = 0;
        for (E e : es) {
            s.acquireUninterruptibly();
            switch(e) {
            case A:
                final int i_ = i;
                new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                        System.out.println("A" + i_); s(); s.release();
                    }
                }.start();
                break;
            case B:
                final int i_ = i;
                new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                        System.out.println("B" + i_); s(); s.release();
                    }
                }.start();
                break;
            case C:
                new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                        System.out.println("C"); s(); s.release();
                    }
                }.start();
                break;
            case D:
                new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                        System.out.println("D"); s(); s.release();
                    }
                }.start();
                break;
            case E:
                new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                        System.out.println("E"); s(); s.release();
                    }
                }.start();
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

It spawns threads to do work. Which work to do is decided by the current element from the input list `es`. A semaphore is used to bound the number of currently running threads.

It fails to compile, claiming that `i` is already defined:

```
$ javac A.java && java A
A.java:27: i_ is already defined in main(java.lang.String[])
                final int i_ = i;
                          ^
1 error
```

But they are defined in different cases of the switch. I assumed it would work since you can do the same with any other type of block, for example this works:

```
class A {
    static {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            int j = i + 1;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            int j = i + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Why doesn't it work with the switch? What other ways are there to capture a counter around the switch inside anonymous classes inside multiple cases?

Comment: The entire switch is a block, not the separate cases. (Unless you add braces as suggested in an answer -- or only declare the variable once, before the switch-statement)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add braces:

```
case A: {
    ...
}
case B: {
    ...
}
...
```

As you have it, all `i_` declarations are in the same scope, which results in a compilation error. Two pieces of code that are nested at the same level within `{}` braces are always in the same scope, so the fact that the declarations are in different `case`s makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Just zip the indices with the list. This has been a common idiom since some decades ago in ML et al. I argue this approach is cleaner than the one by arshajii, since it also eliminates the stray `i++`. Also, most Java users are unfamiliar with plain blocks around a case (then again, they might be just as surprised by seeing `zip`). My code would be shorter if you used a library that contains `zip`. or it was in the standard library like it should be. I attached an implementation to the bottom of your class.

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.*;
enum E {A,B,C,D,E}
class A {
    static void s() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    static Semaphore s = new Semaphore(2); // 2 cores
    public static void main(String[] _){
        LinkedList<E> es = new LinkedList<E>();
        es.push(E.A);
        es.push(E.D);
        es.push(E.B);
        es.push(E.C);
        es.push(E.E);
        es.push(E.C);
        es.push(E.C);
        es.push(E.E);
        es.push(E.A);
        es.push(E.A);
        f(es);
    }
    static void f(List<E> es) {
        for (final Pair<Integer,E> p : zip(naturals, es)) {
            s.acquireUninterruptibly();
            switch(p.y) {
            case A:
                new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                        System.out.println("A" + p.x); s(); s.release();
                    }
                }.start();
                break;
            case B:
                new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                        System.out.println("B" + p.x); s(); s.release();
                    }
                }.start();
                break;
            case C:
                new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                        System.out.println("C"); s(); s.release();
                    }
                }.start();
                break;
            case D:
                new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                        System.out.println("D"); s(); s.release();
                    }
                }.start();
                break;
            case E:
                new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                        System.out.println("E"); s(); s.release();
                    }
                }.start();
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // an infinite iterable over all natural numbers
    static Iterable<Integer> naturals = new Iterable<Integer>() {
        public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
            return new Iterator<Integer>() {
                private int i = 0;
                public void remove() {
                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                }
                public Integer next() {
                    return i++;
                }
                public boolean hasNext() {
                    return true;
                }
            };
        }
    };

    // combine two iterators
    static <X,Y> Iterable<Pair<X,Y>> zip(final Iterable<X> i1,
                                         final Iterable<Y> i2) {
        return new Iterable<Pair<X,Y>>() {
            public Iterator<Pair<X,Y>> iterator() {
                return new Iterator<Pair<X,Y>>() {
                    private final Iterator<X> ix = i1.iterator();
                    private final Iterator<Y> iy = i2.iterator();
                    public void remove() {
                        ix.remove();
                        iy.remove();
                    }
                    public Pair<X,Y> next() {
                        Pair<X,Y> p = new Pair<X,Y>();
                        p.x = ix.next();
                        p.y = iy.next();
                        return p;
                    }
                    public boolean hasNext() {
                        return ix.hasNext() && iy.hasNext();
                    }
                };
            }
        };
    }
}

class Pair<X,Y> {
    X x;
    Y y;
}
```

---

```
javac A.java && java A
A0
A1
E
C
C
E
C
B7
D
A9
```